# Why my UI Controls are resizing based on the screen of simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am new at Swift.
I am designing a screen with xib file for the size of iPhone 6 , and i have some controls in it, when i run in iPhone 6Plus simulator controls are getting bigger, how to fix this to get controls in the same size in all devices.
Thank you.

Comment: Try to work with constraints!

Comment: You best bet is to use size classes in Storyboard

Comment: use size classes and put some constraints on uicontrols after that it will look similar on any iphone simulator

Comment: Thank you, all your answers are correct, i fixed with contraints.

Answer (score 1):

1- Open your xib file

2- In Utilities tab you should see like this[image]

3- In Autoresizing part you need to disable all inner arrows . Before disable it it looks like[image]

after disable its looks

[image]

**Thats it!! Now your view have constant size!**